# How to get url to action method from ModelViewSet(Django Rest Framework) with reverse function?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have this ModelViewSet class:

```
class DriveInvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_fields = ('location_id', 'logical_deleted')
    permission_classes = (UserCanManageFacilityPermission,)
    pagination_class = None

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def get_subtotals_by_unit(self, request):
        invoices_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        grouped_invoices = get_subtotals_by_unit(invoices_list)

        return Response(grouped_invoices)
```

How can I get the URL from reverse function to test the **get_subtotals_by_unit** action?

The ViewSet registred by the router **router.register('drive_invoices', DriveInvoiceViewSet, base_name='drive_invoices')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **`action`** decorator slightly as below,

```
class DriveInvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # other code
    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path="/some/path/", url_name="some-view-name")
    def get_subtotals_by_unit(self, request):
        invoices_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        grouped_invoices = get_subtotals_by_unit(invoices_list)
        return Response(grouped_invoices)
```

Thus, DRF will create a url pattern with a view name with a syntax as **`<router_base_name>-<action_view_name>`**
Thus, the view name in your case will be,  **drive_invoices-some-view-name**

Answer (score 0):

Change the action decorator slightly as below:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='parent/(?P<role_id>\w+)')
def get_org(self, request, role_id):
# Your method implementation
```

Register the ViewSet with the Router:

1. List item Use a standard URL path for registering the OrganizationViewSet with the router. The custom action's URL will be built based on this.
   Ensure you import DefaultRouter from the correct Django REST framework module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).